# Duda Complemento Directo/Indirecto con verbo "hacer sentir"

Tags: pronombres, objetos-indirectos, complemento-directo

Creo que tengo la mente hecha un caos y probablemente le esté dando vueltas a algo muy simple. Pero soy un poco novato en esto y me he quedado en blanco...

A ver si me podéis ayudar a resolver esta duda. Es la siguiente frase:

> El agua fría hizo sentir como nueva a Marta.

En este caso, ¿"a Marta" qué sería?, ¿complemento indirecto o directo?

1. Primer método: sustitución por el pronombre:

> El agua fría **la** hizo sentir como nueva.
>
> El agua fría **le** hizo sentir como nueva.

Ambas me suenan bien. Si fuera masculino sería "el agua fría **lo** hizo sentir como nuevo". No me termina de convencer pero no sé si podría funcionar.

2. Segundo Método: preguntar por: ¿a quién?

¿A quién hizo sentir como nueva el agua fría? A Marta. Sí, pero no me fío. Por ejemplo:

> El agua refrescó a Marta.

¿A quién refrescó el agua? A Marta. Según esto "a Marta" debería ser CI, pero:

> Marta fue refrescada por el agua.
>
> El agua la refrescó.

Aquí es CD, ¿no?

3. Tercer método: pasarlo a pasiva.

> Como nueva fue sentida Marta por el agua fría. ¿? ¿? ¿?
>
> Marta fue sentida como nueva por el agua fría. ¿? ¿? ¿?

No sé ni cómo realizarla La verdad. Yo voto por el CI, pero necesitaría confirmación.

¿Algún método infalible para detectar los CI?

Comment: En casos como estos, sustituye el OD también: "Se lo hizo sentir". "Lo" se refiere a "sentir como nueva" y "se" a "Marta". Y "se" se usa en lugar de "le" cuando el OD está ya pronominalizado. Ahí puedes ver que, sin pronominalizar el OD, la frase es con "le" referido a Marta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A Marta* es **complemento *indirecto***, porque Marta no es el objeto, sino destinataria de la acción y del complemento directo.

Aquí el **verbo** es *hacer* en su sentido de *obligar*. De acuerdo al [DLE, (acepción 33)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jwhmcap), requiere como objeto un verbo en infinitivo.

Como consecuencia, el **complemento directo** sería el infinitivo (*sentir*). Concuerdo con [Carlos Alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/carlos-alejo) en que a juzgar por el diccionario, parece más correcto *sentirse*, aunque el primero me suena por lo menos a un uso coloquial sufiententemente extendido como para no temer elegirlo.

*Como nueva* sería una frase adverbial que hace las veces de **complemento circunstancial** en la frase original (*Marta se siente como nueva*) aunque aquí se podría argumentar que complementa al objeto (CD). La definición del DLE de [como](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9xWxEd9) sugiere varias alternativas en las que esa palabra podría actuar como pronombre relativo, quizá con alguna palabra omitida (como [*mujer* nueva](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hombre_nuevo), como *si fuera* nueva) o con *nueva* actuando como adjetivo sustantivado.

Comment: Me cuadra más la acepción 6 de hacer: "causar, ocasionar". El agua ocasionó que Marta se sintiera como nueva. No la obligó a nada. Como comentaba, por dos veces concluí que era complemento indirecto, y realmente cuadra con lo que dices de que Marta es la destinataria de la acción. Pero entonces ¿cuál es la forma pasiva? ¿Sentirse como nueva fue hecho por el agua a Marta?

Comment: Vale, acabo de verlo. La frase se podría escribir (de forma algo forzada) como "El agua ocasionó una sensación de estar como nueva a Marta". En este caso la pasiva sería "Una sensación de estar como nueva fue ocasionada por el agua a Marta", que resulta coherente. Así que al final sí que era complemento indirecto. Modifico mi respuesta, pues, y te doy mi voto positivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos, Carlos Alejo y Rafael. Todo me ha quedado más claro. Aunque en el caso que quiera cambiar la frase, por ejemplo: El agua fría hizo a Marta sentirse como nueva. ¿Sería correcta? Seguiría siendo CI, ¿no? La frase original de donde venía mi duda era la siguiente: Marta se lavó la cara, el agua fría la refrescó y la revitalizó, haciéndo**le** sentir como nueva.

Comment: @Nova10 si inviertes el orden de los elementos no cambia la función de cada uno. Y en la frase original, "le" indica complemento indirecto igualmente.

Answer (score 2):

La [respuesta de Rafael](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18087/12637) tiene toda la razón, y yo me equivocaba. En realidad podemos interpretar la frase como:

> El agua fría ocasionó una sensación de estar como nueva a Marta.

La cual tiene la siguiente voz pasiva:

> Una sensación de estar como nueva fue ocasionada por el agua fría a Marta.

Con lo que, efectivamente, el complemento directo de la oración original es *sentir como nueva* y *a Marta* sería **complemento indirecto**.

---

**RESPUESTA ANTERIOR** (RESPETADA A MODO TESTIMONIAL, **SE RUEGA NO TENER EN CUENTA**)

Tras varias divagaciones, juraría que la confusión viene de que la oración no está bien planteada. En este caso, el infinitivo del verbo sería *sentirse como nuevo*, es decir, se hace uso del verbo *[sentir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XbV5cZG%7CXbVfLnt)* en una de sus acepciones como verbo pronominal:

> 11. prnl. Hallarse o estar de determinada manera.

Por lo que la frase en realidad debería expresarse así:

> El agua fría hizo sentirse como nueva a Marta.

Si el verbo sentir no es pronominal, entonces es transitivo, requiriendo un complemento directo tal que así: "Marta sintió un escalofrío provocado por el agua fría", o "el agua fría hizo sentir un escalofrío a Marta". En esta última, "a Marta" sí sería un complemento indirecto, ya que el directo es el escalofrío. Pasiva: "un escalofrío fue hecho sentir por el agua fría a Marta".

Volviendo al ejemplo corregido, una frase así expresada quedaría un tanto rara en pasiva:

> Marta fue hecha sentirse como nueva por el agua fría.

Lo que normalmente se suele expresar como:

> Marta se sintió como nueva por el agua fría.

Al ser ahora Marta el sujeto de la oración, comprobamos que en la oración original su papel es el de **complemento directo**.

El truco de pasarla a pasiva suele dar buenos resultados, sólo que a veces la construcción pasiva no es obvia e incluso en algunos casos directamente no existe.

En todo caso, una pista puede ser que los complementos indirectos pueden sustituir la preposición *a* por *para*. El ejemplo más típico es "Juan le escribió una carta a Pepe" que equivale a "Juan escribió una carta para Pepe". Siguiendo esta norma, que la verdad es que no sé si funciona en todos los casos, en tu ejemplo *a* no se podría sustituir por *para*. Así que "a Marta" sería complemento directo. Si la frase fuese "Marta le hizo una tarta a Elena", ahí si se podría sustituir: "Marta hizo una tarta para Elena".

Comment: Concuerdo en casi todo, excepto: 1) _Marta se hizo sentir como nueva_ no me suena del todo correcta, quizás _fue hecha sentir como nueva por el agua_ sea más correcto, aunque no menos forzado 2) Creo que en realidad es complemento _indirecto_.

Comment: @Rafael tuve que escribir tres veces la respuesta hasta dar con una que me cuadrase. Las dos primeras veces que escribí la respuesta mi conclusión fue en ambas que era complemento indirecto. Estoy totalmente abierto a que demostréis que me equivoco, dado que dudé un montón antes de redactar la definitiva.

Comment: Me parece que el _se_ del verbo pronominal y el de la pasiva refleja son distintos. Fíjate que el [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XNTSeAe) los pone en acepciones distintas. Si fueran iguales, aplicaría el _María fue sentida_, y en ese caso sería que otros la sintieron, lo que al menos a mí me choca un poco

Comment: @Rafael tienes toda la razón, voy a actualizar la respuesta.