# Laísmo/leísmo con el verbo "hacer" con el significado de "obligar": ¿Cómo escribo "a la conductora que iba detrás de mí *la/le* hice frenar"?

Tags: gramática, laísmo-leísmo-loísmo

Tengo una duda con el verbo "hacer" con el significado de "obligar". En el siguiente caso, ¿se ha de usar "le" o "la"?:

> Di un frenazo brusco, y a la conductora que iba detrás de mí **la/le** hice frenar.

Con el significado más habitual de hacer creo que no tengo dudas:

> Le hice un regalo a María.
>
> Esta tarta la hice yo.

Sin embargo, con el significado de "obligar", no lo tengo nada claro.

Por ejemplo, si en la frase anterior, en vez de "hice" uso "obligué", creo que lo correcto es "la" (aunque no estoy 100% seguro).

De todos modos, no estoy seguro de si el truco -por así llamarlo- de la sustitución es válido. Es decir, no estoy seguro de que si usando "obligué" he de poner "la", entonces también he de poner "la" para "hice".

Comment: En _[Duda Complemento Directo/Indirecto con verbo “hacer sentir”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18085/12637)_ tienes una pregunta muy similar, cuyas respuestas te pueden ayudar con tu duda concreta. Avísanos si es así, y si no dinos en qué se diferencia tu duda para poderte ayudar mejor. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si el verbo que sigue a "hacer" es intransitivo, se usa LO / LA / LOS / LAS:

- Lo hice frenar (a él).
- La hice frenar (a ella).
- Los hice frenar (a ellos).
- Las hice frenar (a ellas).

Si el verbo que sigue a "hacer" es transitivo, se usa LE / LES:

- Le hice frenar el coche (a él / a ella).
- Les hice frenar el coche (a ellos / a ellas).

En [este sitio](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Foro/ARCHIVO-Foro/La%C3%ADsmo-le%C3%ADsmo-lo%C3%ADsmo.htm) se explica claramente que usar "le" cuando el verbo que sigue a "hacer" es intransitivo es un caso de leísmo:

Leísmo:

-¿Vino Anabel?
–Sí, le hice venir porque su padre quería hablar con ella.

Correcto:

-¿Vino Anabel?
–Sí, la hice venir porque su padre quería hablar con ella.

Leísmo:

-¿Cómo es que está hoy Juan en la oficina? ¿No estaba de vacaciones?
–Sí, pero el jefe le hizo venir porque lo necesitaba urgentemente.

Correcto:

-¿Cómo es que está hoy Juan en la oficina? ¿No estaba de vacaciones?
–Sí, pero el jefe lo hizo venir porque lo necesitaba urgentemente